# How to count number of JSON objects in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can one in Ruby "generically" count the number of objects for JSONs in the below formats (rooted, unrooted)? By generically, I mean the elements may be different ("title" for instance by be called something else).

without root:

```
{
    [
      { "title": "Post 1", "body": "Hello!" },
      { "title": "Post 2", "body": "Goodbye!" }
    ]
}
```

root wrapped:

```
{
  "posts":
    [
      { "title": "Post 1", "body": "Hello!" },
      { "title": "Post 2", "body": "Goodbye!" }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Firstly, `without root` code is not a valid json format. It would be without surrounding curly brackets, so I'm gona assume that's how it should be.

In first case:

```
json = '[
  { "title": "Post 1", "body": "Hello!" },
  { "title": "Post 2", "body": "Goodbye!" }
]'

require 'json'
ary = JSON.parse(json)
puts ary.count
```

The other case is not much different:

```
json = '{
  "posts":
    [
      { "title": "Post 1", "body": "Hello!" },
      { "title": "Post 2", "body": "Goodbye!" }
    ]
}')

require 'json'
hash = JSON.parse(json)
puts hash['posts'].count
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Some frameworks - such as  AngularJS - only consumes JSON without its root.